# With c#, Variable passing does not work

Tags: c#

I am amateur. I want to pass variables to the next private class Exec. But the value is null. There is a problem with this source. Please teach me.

1. I want to get all folders path with class form.
2. Then, I want to loop "xml files" in folders by the following processing.

Here is my `class form` :

```
public partial class form : Form
{
    public form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string XmlFolderPath;
    private string XsltFilePath;

    public string XmlFolderPath1 => XmlFolderPath;
    public string XsltFilePath1 => XsltFilePath;


    //XMLフォルダ選択
    private void ButtonXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dr = new FolderBrowserDialog
        {
            Description = "Xml ファイルが格納されたフォルダを選択してください"
        };

        DialogResult result = dr.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            XmlFolder.Text = dr.SelectedPath;
            XmlFolderPath = XmlFolder.Text;
        }
    }

    //XSLTファイル選択
    private void ButtonXslt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Title = "XSLT ファイルのみを選択してください",
            Filter = "Xslt File (*.xslt)|*.xslt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        };

        DialogResult result = file.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            XsltFile.Text = file.FileName;
            XsltFilePath = XsltFile.Text;               
        }
    }

    //キャンセルボタン＋ESC
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void FolderSelect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void RunHtml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Enabled = true;
        MessageBox.Show(XmlFolderPath);
        Exec run = new Exec();
        run.RunHTML();
    }
}

private class Exec: form 
{
    public void RunHTML()
    {
       form form = new form(); 
       MessageBox.Show(form.XmlFolderPath1); 
       MessageBox.Show(form.XsltFilePath1);
    } 
}
```

Comment: private class Exec: form
 {
  public void RunHTML()
  {
   form form = new form();
   MessageBox.Show(form.XmlFolderPath1);
   MessageBox.Show(form.XsltFilePath1);
  }
 }

Comment: Don´t add code in comments. Instead edit your question. Apart from this: what is null? Can you be a bit more specific on your problem please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line within your `Exec` class:

```
form form = new form();
```

In this line, you see the `new` keyword. That means you are creating a new instance. But you need to obtain the XmlFolderpath from an instance you already have.

One possible solution is to pass the instance in. First, modify your Exec class:

```
public void RunHTML(form existingInstance)
{
   MessageBox.Show(existingInstance.XmlFolderPath1); 
   MessageBox.Show(existingInstance.XsltFilePath1);
}
```

Now modify the caller to pass the form:

```
Exec run = new Exec();
run.RunHTML(this);
```

Now you are passing the existing form into the RunHTML method, and the method can now read the values.

There are other ways to do this-- for example, you could pass the form into Exec's constructor-- and you're free to pick and choose what works best in your situation. But the answer above should get you going.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I solved. And I'm sorry. Please teach me. If I use accession [public class Exec: form], Can I write code in a smart way?